# I Want to get right time on Android Device, what I do for Expression like 1 * new Date(); in Javascript same in Android?

Tags: java, javascript, android

If I run this in browser;

```
1 * new Date();
```

I get the time: `1369837120265`. I want to get same in my Android app.

Because Android connects to the internet, is there any guarantee that the time I get will be right? Is there any API to do this? How can I get the same time from Android?

My app is Java based, and I want to evaluate the time like how I evaluate in browser using JavaScript.

Thanks

@Djon

I want to know a thing more in my question.

As in question if device use internet and it is connect then it will work fine.

What about last time When My tablet is offline and have set wrong time. If wrong time happen more time and user not have correct it then.

1. in Case of Phablet (SIM based tablet) Is their Any way to get time. I am not sure but My nokia & samesung phone take time from The Call service provider.
2. Because the tablet I own not have SIM nor connect to internet. Now is their anyway to get correct time without bother user to change the time correctly.

I means in 2nd case offline app. (just for example) is this possible to get right time.

Comment: @downvote, Can you tell me why downvote, I will take care of it if you tell me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same: `Date date = new Date();` and you can then use `long millis = date.getTime()` to retrieve a `long` containing milliseconds.

If you don't need an object, you can also use `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

```
1 * System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Comment: I'd say go with the System.getCurrentMillis() if all you're looking for is the epoch time.

Comment: Thanks, it's working. Sometime Android (offline) have wrong time. Do you have something for that. I means just for example.

Comment: I don't understand, if the device is not connected o the internet and has an inacurate time, there is no way for you to know.

Comment: Sorry, I should have precised that I know nothing about Android, only Java. (But you can still accept my answer)

Answer (score 0):

What you get ist the [Unix Timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). To get this timestamp in Java just write:

```
Date date = new Date();
```

and with

```
System.out.println("Today is " + date.getTime());
```

you can output the time in milliseconds. It will also be a [Unix Timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).